# Java Reflection to call methods with multiple parameters

Tags: java, methods, reflection

Hi I am using Java reflections to call methods and pass parameters to the methods.
here is the sample code

```
package com.tests;
public class base
{
void method1(String username,String Pwd)
{System.out.println("method with 2 parameters "+username+" "+pwd);
}
void method2(String username,String Pwd)
{
System.out.println("\n method2 with 2 parameters "+username+" "+pwd);
    }
void method3(String username,String Pwd)
{System.out.println("\n method3 with 2 parameters "+username+" "+pwd);}
}
```

Piece of code used to invoke methods

```
    java.lang.reflect.Method method;
        try 
        {
         method= obj.getClass().getMethod(test,String.class,String.class);
         method.invoke(obj,"user1","pwd");
           } 
        catch (SecurityException e) 
        {System.out.println("SECURITY EXCEPTION :"+e);}
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
        {System.out.println("NoSuchMethodException EXCEPTION :"+e);}
```

where   test="method1" /"method2"/"method3"
obj is object of base class
the above code is throwing NOSuchmethodException

Comment: What's the value of `test`?

Comment: Please note: when writing "its not working" questions, then provide **all** relevant information. Besides: please study the java coding style guidelines. Your class and variable names are kinda ... all wrong. Classes start with uppercase, variables and parameters do not.

Comment: Generic hints on reflection: a) don't use it ... and b) read the available javadoc/tutorials **really really careful**. There is a ton of stuff that can go wrong, starting with public vs non-public visibility of fields/methods ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for `Class<?>` you'll see that `getMethod(...)` and `getMethods()` return only the public member methods.

In your code, the methods aren't public so they are not found. What you want to use instead is `getDeclaredMethod(...)`.

Tested it right now, and it works.